# Working with STM32 flash memories.. on renode

Tags: microcontroller, memory, flash

I am a newbie on embedded flash memories and in particular my university assigned me a job with them on a stm32f407 MCU.

I have to work with renode (don't ask me why, they want so) and it has 0 support for flash memories. I am ready to write a peripheral for the renode simulator and to do a pull request if it goes well but first of all I need to understand well how embedded flash memories work.

In particular I need to write a sort of log in the flash memory, a kind of <timestamp, event> of fixed bytes length everytime an interrupt occurs.

If I understood the problem well, I first need to erase a sector (and I want to use only the sector #11 that has enough size for me).

[image]

After the erasing, the sector is all 1s so I can program the flash memory on successive addresses without problems right? I know that I can only write a 0 and it can't be converted again to a 1 without erasing the sector, but I need to write only one time at each memory address so a single erase operation at beginning would be fine right?

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds right. You should read the datasheet/user manual carefully so you understand fully. There can be traps like the processor has to execute from ram whilst the flash is writing and you may have to write complete sectors. Knowing these things up front can save a lot of grief later. Sometimes it is easier to use a sdcard or serial flash.

Comment: What's renode? Also, ST provides libs and appnotes how to use the Flash to emulate EEPROM.

Comment: @Justme it's an open source emulator for different platforms. Look [here](https://renode.io/).